# For Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ if $A+n=A$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $\lambda(A)=0$ or $\lambda(A)=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a $\lambda$-measurable set such that $A+n=A$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $\lambda$ is  the Lebesgue measure. Show that if $\lambda(A)\neq 0$ then $\lambda(A)=\infty$.

I think I should build a set $B\subset A$ so that $\lambda(B)=\infty$ but I can not think of how to build this set.

Comment: Hint: if $\lambda(A) \neq 0$, then there is some interval $[N,N+1)$ such that $A \cap [N, N+1)$ has nonzero measure (where $N \in \mathbb Z)$. This is because $A$ is the disjoint union of $A \cap [n,n+1)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hint: Can you describe $A$ in terms of $A_0=A\cap[0,1)$ only?

Comment: @Did how can I do this?

Comment: What? Did you notice I posted a comment with specific instructions? Sorry but simply bouncing them back at me is not a constructive approach.